# Android studio [AndroidManifest.xml] I can't run the program

Tags: android, kotlin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="25"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.my.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.my.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.My" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.my.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.my.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I decided to create a light program and nothing starts for about 5 hours, I think. what is the problem? I just started learning Kotlin yesterday.

Errors:

```
Attribute android:versionCode is not allowed here
Attribute android:versionName is not allowed here
Attribute android:protectionLevel is not allowed here
Attribute android:allowBackup is not allowed here
Attribute android:appComponentFactory is not allowed here
Attribute android:dataExtractionRules is not allowed here
Attribute android:extractNativeLibs is not allowed here
Attribute android:fullBackupContent is not allowed here
Attribute android:icon is not allowed here
Attribute android:supportsRtl is not allowed here
Attribute android:theme is not allowed here
Unresolved class 'InitializationProvider'
Attribute android:exported is not allowed here
```

---

---

---

simple code that prevents it from running on the phone.

I'm new and don't understand anything. What to do?

Comment: Did you create the project in android studio or in another ide ?

Comment: yes in android studio

Comment: mmm, I will suggest you to watch some tutorials - for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBGTeaZB26Y

Comment: hello world everything was fine with me.

Comment: Maybe it's some uninstalled libraries? because I did the code according to the instructions. ctrl+c + ctrl+v?

Answer (score 0):

For this error - Unresolved class 'InitializationProvider'

Add To use Jetpack Startup in your library or app, add the following to your Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1")
}
```

Add code in the manifest file ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    package="com.example.my"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="25"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.my.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.my.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.My" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.my.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.my.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" 
            tools:node="merge">
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" 
                tools:node="remove"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" 
                 tools:node="remove"/>
        </provider>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Does not find the **InitializationProvider** name class.

You can add this dependency.

```
implementation "androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.0.0"
```

and change your manifest like this

```
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove" />
```